# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in Restful

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

In my project using restful json, I have some files following as:

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>   
<context:component-scan base-package="com.totoroads.webservice.android" />
</beans:beans>
```

My Jersey class:

```
@Path("/marker")
public class GetLatLongMapMarker {

@GET 
@Path("/doMarker")
@Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
public String doMap() {

    String carMaps = null;

    ArrayList<CarMap> mapList = new ArrayList<CarMap>();

        try {
            mapList = DBConnection.getAllMapMarker();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            carMaps = gson.toJson(mapList); 
        } 

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    return carMaps;
    }
}
```

When I want to get data from json by URL:

```
http://192.168.1.221:9999/restfulspringmvc/maker/doMarker
```

there is exception has happened, and this is log:

```
02:12:23.239 [http-bio-9999-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet   - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for   [/restfulspringmvc/maker/doMarker]
02:12:23.239 [http-bio-9999-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /maker/doMarker
02:12:23.240 [http-bio-9999-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/maker/doMarker]
02:12:23.241 [http-bio-9999-exec-3] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/restfulspringmvc/maker/doMarker] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
02:12:23.245 [http-bio-9999-exec-3] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

How can I fix this configuration ? 
Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the request mappings in your jersey class this way:

```
@Path("/marker")
public class GetLatLongMapMarker {

@GET 
@Path("/doMarker")
@Produces("application/json;charset=utf-8")
public String doMap() {
```

Which results in /[context-path]/ma**r**ker/doMarker, but you are requesting this url `http://192.168.1.221:9999/restfulspringmvc/maker/doMarker`.

So change `maker` in your request to `marker` and you should be able to reach it

Comment: I have changed from maker to marker, but its same error. its seem happened the problem from servlet-context.xml file